# Rally: Creating a multiple query based filter

Tags: rally

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116069/rally-rest-api-queryfilter-get-defects-by-timestamp) to create a complexQueryFilter.

Here's my code:

```
QueryFilter complexFilter = new QueryFilter("c_TestReady","=","Yes").and(new QueryFilter("c_ExternalID","=",""));
```

The `c_ExternalID` field is a custom field in Rally of type String and `c_TestReady` is another field with values Yes or no. The query should return all test cases that are TestReady and whose ExternalID field is empty.

I also tried:

```
1."c_ExternalID","=",null
2."c_ExternalID","contains",null
3."c_ExternalID","contains",""
```

None of these seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the double quotes, as in `new QueryFilter("c_ExternalID", "=", "\"\"")`

This worked for me:

```
storyRequest.setQueryFilter((new QueryFilter("c_CustomString", "=", "\"\"")).and(new QueryFilter("c_CustomCheckBox", "=", "true")));
```